# How do I pick the bigger data type for my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, types

My function takes two arrays, which store data with a primitive data type.

I would like to pick the bigger data type for my `result` array to prevent data loss
when inserting values into the array.

E.g: The first array stores ints and the second double. The `result` array should have double.

```
template<std::size_t length, typename A1, typename A2>
constexpr auto function(A1 array1, A2 array2){
    //e.g array1 ints, array2 doubles
    //do calculations and insert values into result array
    std::array< ???, length> result{};
    return array3;
}
```

Comment: Generically or just for predefined types? You could simply compare sizeofs I suppose...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the input arrays will have one of the primitive data types. Could be anything, I just want to take the bigger one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to the rescue.  As long as there is a type that both array element types can be converted to, it will give you that type.  So for an `int` and `double`, `std::common_type` would give you `double`.  You can use that for your array like

```
std::array<std::common_type_t<A1::value_type, A2::value_type>, length> result{};
```

Answer (score 3):

[`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

> Determines the common type among all types T..., that is the type all T... can be implicitly converted to. If such a type exists (as determined according to the rules below), the member type names that type. Otherwise, there is no member type.

Answer (score 3):

As @formerlyknownas_463035818 comments, you want to use [std::common_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template<std::size_t length, typename A1, typename A2>
constexpr auto function(A1 array1, A2 array2){
    //e.g array1 ints, array2 doubles
    //do calculations and insert values into result array
    std::array<std::common_type<A1::value_type, A2::value_type>, length> result{};
    return array3;
}
```

Comment: no need to give credits, comment is already gone (and I am thinking to change my nick soon, just waiting for a good idea ;)

Comment: How about formerlyknownas_formerlyknownas_463035818? :-)

Comment: @PaulEvans I see what you did there Mr.Recursion.

Comment: @formerlyknowmas_463035818 Prince was later known as TAFKAP (The Artist Formerly Known As Prince). Maybe this can enspire you.